# Why mysql insert 10 rows without for loop?

Tags: php, mysql

I want something like this, when user press f5 to refresh the webpage, the webpage will compare current time to previous time that stored at session. If current time is 5 seconds away from previous time, then mysql will store data into database. When user refresh the page after 50 seconds, mysql should store 1 data to database, but why mysql store 10 datas to database? The user just refresh the page for 1 time, but mysql insert 10 times. Why this happen? My codes :

```
<?php
if (strtotime($_SESSION[servertime]) < time()-5){ //10800 = 3 hours 3600 = 1 hour   
  $_SESSION['servertime'] = $servertime; 
  $_SESSION['ipaddress'] = $currentipAddress;
  $query = "INSERT INTO traceuser 
              (ibrowser, operatingsystem, ipaddress, datetime, username) 
            VALUES (
             '{$userbrowser}', '{$CurrOS}', '{$currentipAddress}'
             , '{$servertime}', '{$username}')";
  $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
} else {
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('I did not save your info this time, because each visitor can save info for 1 time per 5 seconds.')</script>";
}
?>
```

I think the problem is at this line : `if (strtotime($_SESSION[servertime]) < time()-5)`, when user fresh the page after 50 seconds, mysql will store the data to database for each 5 seconds because 50 seconds - 5 seconds = 10 seconds, so mysql insert 10 rows. How to make mysql insert only 1 row?

**Update :** Found the problem!!! I check my database records every 10 seconds, and I realize that it keep inserting new data for every 10 seconds, eventhough I didn't pres f5 to refresh the page. The problem is because I added Yahoo Ping Box to my website!!! From what I know, Yahoo Ping Box messenger will check new message for every 10 seconds, I am not sure how can Yahoo Ping Box code affect my php/mysql code? May I know how to prevent Yahoo Ping Box code affect my php/mysql code? This is the codes of Yahoo Ping box which cause the problem :

```
<object id="pingboxh57fsuytam000" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://wgweb.msg.yahoo.com/badge/Pingbox.swf" width="610" height="320"><param name="movie" value="http://wgweb.msg.yahoo.com/badge/Pingbox.swf" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="flashvars" value="wid=oCqiyuy8QmXM8PXSd0uhP6Au" /></object>
```

You can test it by copy paste the Yahoo Ping Box code into your php/mysql script, you will see the magic keep inserting records into you database for every 5 to 10 seconds. May I know how to prevent Yahoo Ping Box code affect my php/mysql code?

Comment: Use `$_SESSION['servertime']` instead of `$_SESSION[servertime]`.

Comment: There's no way this code would insert 10 rows unless it was called 10 times.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but why don't I see any `mysql_real_escape()` calls? What if the user modifies its session data to contain something like `servertime="', ''); DELETE FROM traceuser; -- "`?

Comment: I think you have an SQL-injection hole, what happens if the user manipulates his `$userbrowser` id to include malicious SQL code?

Comment: @glglgl, you meant `mysql_real_escape_string()` right?

Comment: @glglgl: In such mysql_query() will raise an error, since it does not support multiple queries. However you are right: there are possibilities to inject SQL into this code.

Comment: @Jon, refresh page per time can call 10 times mysql? Is it depend on browser setting? I have tested it on IE7 and Firefox 3.6. Both of them have this problem.

Comment: @str, I have changed it to `$_SESSION['servertime']`, but the problem still there.

Comment: @glglgl, I don't think I need to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` because my textbox allows 10 characters input only.

Comment: @zac1987 This restriction is for the browser only. If I knit my HTTP request by hand, I can send an appropriate (or in this case: inappropriate) request which doesn't obey the limit.

Comment: @glglgl, I see. Thanks for ur info, I always heard people said mysql_real_escape_string() can't prevent sql injection thou, only PDO prepared statement can't do the job...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your page use ajax, or some other technology which might be hitting your server multiple times per page load?  I agree that the code as written would only be writing once per call.
A way to help figure out what's going on would be to put a breakpoint inside your if clause, or add an error_log() there (if you don't have a debugger set up).  I suspect you'll find that your code is being called multiple times by the client.
Mike

Comment: yes, I do have ajax on my code, but the ajax is to SELECT and show records, nothing related to INSERT record. Only this line of ajax `jQuery.get("showlists.php?servertime=" + servertime + "&usertime=" + usertime, function(itemlists){
  $('#fullList').append(itemlists);  
 });`

Comment: Thanks you because u inspire me to look for "other technology". I found the problem!!! I check my database records every 10 seconds, and I realize that it keep inserting new data for every 10 seconds, eventhough I didn't pres f5 to refresh the page. The problem is because I added Yahoo Ping Box to my website!!! From what I know, Yahoo Ping Box messenger will check new message for every 10 seconds, I am not sure how can Yahoo Ping Box code affect my php/mysql code? May I know how to prevent Yahoo Ping Box code affect my php/mysql code? I have show the code of Yahoo Ping Box onto my question.